# Form doesn't get values from Request

Tags: php, symfony

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
I think I've done it exactly like  My form class:

```
class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder
        ->add("name",TextType::class)
        ->add("price",IntegerType::class)
    ;
  }

  public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
  {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => Product::class,
        ));
   }
}
```

And in the controller:

```
public function createAction (Request $request)
{

    $product=new Product();
    $form=$this->createForm(ProductType::class,$product);
    $response=new JsonResponse();
    $form->handleRequest($request);


    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($product);
        $entityManager->flush();
        $response->setContent(array('id',$product->getId()));
        $response->setStatusCode('201');
    }
    else{
        $response->setData(array('Error','Invalid form'));
        $response->setStatusCode('400');
    }
    return $response;
}
```

But it doesn't work.
$request does get the values, but $form->handleRequest($request) does nothing.

Edit:

```
new JsonResponse($form)        -> {}
$request->get("name")          -> ProductName (what I sent)
$request->get("price")         -> 13 (what I sent)

$form->getErrors(true,true)) :

FormErrorIterator {#450 ▼
  -form: Form {#437 ▼
  -config: FormBuilder {#438 ▶}
  -parent: null
  -children: OrderedHashMap {#439 ▶}
  -errors: []
-submitted: false
-clickedButton: null
-modelData: Product {#331 ▶}
-normData: Product {#331 ▶}
-viewData: Product {#331 ▶}
-extraData: []
-transformationFailure: null
-defaultDataSet: true
-lockSetData: false
  }
  -errors: []
}
```

Also both "$form->getConfig()->getMethod()" and "$request->getMethod()" are 'POST'.

Comment: Can you add the errors contained in the form by returning it in your else part. You can use something like : `return new JsonResponse($form)` or you can var_dump it.

Comment: Can you post the dump of your request params? can you post the content of dump($form->getErrors(true,true))?

Comment: Thank you! They are added in the main question.

Comment: Does your form have a name prefix? for example product['name']

Comment: No, where it says "ProductName" it's because I wrote "ProductName". Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't have $this->render() in your method `createAction`.

I think you call your controller with twig function :

```
{{ render(controller( ... )) }}
```

If that is the case, use `MasterRequest` :

```
$form->handleRequest($this->get('request_stack')->getMasterRequest());
```

Comment: Why render a JsonResponse? (probably called by ajax)

Comment: Exactly, I don't want it to "show" anything, just get the JsonResponse. Thanks anyway!